# java-spring-mvc Form values not getting printed on POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am new to spring mvc 
i created a project using SpringTemplateProject and used hibernate in that.

i created a form and on post the values are getting inserted in database but the problem is i am not able to display those values on POST.

here is the code.

//Controller

```
package com.projects.data;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.projects.data.*;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Autowired
ServiceImpl service;


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)        
public String customer(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,Model model)
{
    service.addCustomer(customer);
            return "customer/customer";
}
}
```

Home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<spring:url var="customer" value="/customer"/>
<form:form action="${customer}" method="post" modelAttribute="customer" commandName="custform">
<form:label path="custid">Id:</form:label>
<form:input path="custid"/> <br>

<form:label path="name">Name:</form:label>
<form:input path="name"/> <br>

<form:label path="age">Age:</form:label>
<form:input path="age"/> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Save"/>    
</form:form>
</html>
```

customer.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Submitted Information</title>
</head>
 <body>

<h2>Submitted Information</h2>
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>Customer id</td>
    <td>${custform.custid}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>${custform.name}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>${custform.age}</td>
 </tr>
 </table> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Data is getting inserted in the database but it is not getting displayed.Please help me resolve this.

I tried using @modelAttribute

```
model.addAttribute("custid",customer.getCustId());
model.addAttribute("name", customer.getName());
model.addAttribute("age", customer.getAge());
```

But this also does not seem to work.

Model Class

```
package com.projects.data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CUST_ID")
    int custId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    String name;

    @Column(name="AGE")
    int age;

    public Customer(int custId,String name,int age)
    {
        this.custId=custId;
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    //getter and setter methods

    public Customer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }
    public void setCustId(int custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the inserted user in the database have the correct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `custform.` from `${custform.age}`,`${custform.name}` and `${custform.custid}` in jsp and keep yout model.addAttribute as it is in controller. You should be able to access `age` from customer using `${age}` in jsp.

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,Model model)
{
    service.addCustomer(customer);
    model.addAttribute("custid",customer.getCustId());
    model.addAttribute("name", customer.getName());
    model.addAttribute("age", customer.getAge());
    return "customer/customer";
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Submitted Information</title>
</head>
 <body>

<h2>Submitted Information</h2>
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>Customer id</td>
    <td>${custid}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>${name}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>${age}</td>
 </tr>
 </table> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

### **OR**

simply do `model.addAttribute("custform",customer);` in controller and leave everything else as it is.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,Model model)
{
    service.addCustomer(customer);
    model.addAttribute("custform",customer);
    return "customer/customer";
}
```

**JSP**
Keep it same as in question.

Comment: @hey Thanks it worked but i am not able to see my custid dat value is not getting displayed.

Comment: change `<form:label path="custid">Id:</form:label>
<form:input path="custid"/>`  to `<form:label path="custId">Id:</form:label>
<form:input path="custId"/>` and if you are going with second method which I mentioned then use `${custform.custId}` to access `custId`. Everything is case sensitive in java ;)

Comment: hey i changed all custid to custId but still after i debug i see its name as 'custid' and still it is zero..how do i update it??

Comment: Which method you are using? I think you will need to clear cache. If you are using Eclipse, clean and build the project and it should work.

Comment: Hey i did clean and build now all values are updated from custid to custId..but still it is taking value 0.

Comment: Check field name in Customer class of `custId`. I am not sure where the issue is. But it has to do something with `custId` in Customer class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29848/discussion-between-santosh-pingale-and-mvc-nhibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer)
{
    service.addCustomer(customer);

    Model model = new ModelMap();
    model.addAttribute("custid",customer.getCustId());
    model.addAttribute("name", customer.getName());
    model.addAttribute("age", customer.getAge());


    return new ModelAndView("customer/customer", model);
}
```

BTW: A better approach is to redirect (http code 303) to a customer show page, after the post. Then the user can Reload the Page (F5) without creating a new customer while each refresh.

Comment: hey thanks it worked but now i am not getting custid value..i get custid as 0